# Bitmap's getPixel() method apparently runs incorrectly, if the amount of pixels it too high. Is there a solution?

Tags: android

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<Integer> pixels = numberToPixels(textToEncrypt.length());
            encryptedImage.setPixel(0, 0, Color.rgb(pixels.get(0), pixels.get(1), pixels.get(2)));
            int count = 0;
            int characterAt = 0;
            int redValueOfPreviousPixel = 0;
            int greenValueOfPreviousPixel = 0;
            int blueValueOfPreviousPixel = 0;
            for(int y = 0; y < Global_Variables.getImageHeight(); y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < Global_Variables.getImageWidth(); x++) {
                    if(count == setPixelsEvery && characterAt < textToEncrypt.length()) {
                        char c = textToEncrypt.charAt(characterAt);
                        if(c == ',') {
                            c = '~';
                        }
                        else if(c == '\n') {
                            c = 'µ';
                        }

                        String pixelVariation = getPixelForCharacter(c);

                        if(x != 0) {
                            redValueOfPreviousPixel = Color.red(encryptedImage.getPixel(x - 1, y));
                            greenValueOfPreviousPixel = Color.green(encryptedImage.getPixel(x - 1, y));
                            blueValueOfPreviousPixel = Color.blue(encryptedImage.getPixel(x - 1, y));

                        }
                        else {
                            redValueOfPreviousPixel = Color.red((encryptedImage.getPixel(encryptedImage.getWidth() - 1, y - 1)));
                            greenValueOfPreviousPixel = Color.red((encryptedImage.getPixel(encryptedImage.getWidth() - 1, y - 1)));
                            blueValueOfPreviousPixel = Color.red((encryptedImage.getPixel(encryptedImage.getWidth() - 1, y - 1)));
                        }

                        if(pixelVariation.contains("Red")) {
                            pixelVariation.replace("Red ", "");
                            String newPixelVariation = "";
                            boolean found = false;
                            for(int i = 0; i < pixelVariation.length(); i++) {
                                if(pixelVariation.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                                    found = true;
                                }
                                else if(found) {
                                    newPixelVariation += pixelVariation.charAt(i);
                                }
                            }

                            if(redValueOfPreviousPixel < 200) {
                                encryptedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(redValueOfPreviousPixel + Integer.parseInt(newPixelVariation), greenValueOfPreviousPixel, blueValueOfPreviousPixel));
                            }
                            else {
                                encryptedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(redValueOfPreviousPixel - Integer.parseInt(newPixelVariation), greenValueOfPreviousPixel, blueValueOfPreviousPixel));
                            }

                        }
                        else if(pixelVariation.contains("Green")) {
                            String newPixelVariation = "";
                            boolean found = false;
                            for(int i = 0; i < pixelVariation.length(); i++) {
                                if(pixelVariation.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                                    found = true;
                                }
                                else if(found) {
                                    newPixelVariation += pixelVariation.charAt(i);
                                }
                            }

                            if(greenValueOfPreviousPixel < 200) {
                                encryptedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(redValueOfPreviousPixel, greenValueOfPreviousPixel + Integer.parseInt(newPixelVariation), blueValueOfPreviousPixel));
                            }
                            else {
                                encryptedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(redValueOfPreviousPixel, greenValueOfPreviousPixel - Integer.parseInt(newPixelVariation), blueValueOfPreviousPixel));
                            }
                        }
                        else if(pixelVariation.contains("Blue")) {
                            pixelVariation.replace("Blue ", "");
                            String newPixelVariation = "";
                            boolean found = false;
                            for(int i = 0; i < pixelVariation.length(); i++) {
                                if(pixelVariation.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                                    found = true;
                                }
                                else if(found) {
                                    newPixelVariation += pixelVariation.charAt(i);
                                }
                            }

                            if(blueValueOfPreviousPixel < 200) {
                                encryptedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(redValueOfPreviousPixel, greenValueOfPreviousPixel, blueValueOfPreviousPixel + Integer.parseInt(newPixelVariation)));
                            }
                            else {
                                encryptedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(redValueOfPreviousPixel, greenValueOfPreviousPixel, blueValueOfPreviousPixel - Integer.parseInt(newPixelVariation)));
                            }
                        }
                        characterAt ++;
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    count ++;
                }
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(encryptedImage.getWidth() * encryptedImage.getHeight() > 30000000) {
                        Log.d("Tester", "Image too large");
                        int newHeight = showEncryptedImage.getHeight();
                        int newWidth = (int) ((double) newHeight * ((double) encryptedImage.getWidth() / (double) encryptedImage.getHeight()));
                        showEncryptedImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(encryptedImage, newWidth, newHeight, false));
                    }
                    else {
                        showEncryptedImage.setImageBitmap(encryptedImage);
                    }
                    showEncryptionStatus.setText("Encrypted image:");
                    saveImgBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

I have created an app, which encodes text messages into a picture and vice versa. Therefore I have to set specific Pixels to specific rgb-values. This method works fine for images below 10 Megapixels or something like that. But at 12 Megapixels an above the setPixel() method of Bitmap just sets slightly wrong values. E.g I set red to 20, green to 38 and blue to 0. But after I checked the exact same pixel I got different values for some reason. The weird thing is, that this doesn't seem to be a problem for small images. I've also tried it with different alpha configurations with the same result.
After I've set the pixel I've checked them and beside the color I expected to change the other two behaved unnormal (changed too).
My code basically looks out for the previous pixel values and changes ONE specific rgb-value of the actual pixel in relation to the previuos one, but when this bitmap is too large the other rgb-values change too

Comment: You should probably show some code that illustrates what you're doing, what you expect, and how you're verifying it's incorrect. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You shouldn't be calling getPixel and setPixel like this anyway-  incredibly inefficient.  Dump the bitmap as an array and change the array data directly, then reimport it into a Bitmap if needed.